# How to get subarray from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I got array like:

```
Array
(
  [country_location] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [location] => India
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [location] => United States of America
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [location] => South Africa
            )

    )

  [region_location] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [regionname] => Africa
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [regionname] => Antarctica
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [regionname] => Asia
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [regionname] => Europe
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [regionname] => North america
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [regionname] => Oceania (Australia)
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [regionname] => South america
            )

    )

)
```

I tried to get value using $arrayname['country_location'] but its showing Message:  Illegal string offset 'country_location'.

Comment: And your question is ...? How to access the inner Arrays?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: Can we have a bit of code? The error you are seeing is because you are trying to access an array key on a string... So either you are using the wrong variable or it does not have the expected content...

Comment: Use this: `highlight_string(print_r($arrayname, TRUE));` and look if you got some spaces or hidden html tags in your keys

Comment: i need subarray country_location and region_location @Wojciech Jasiński.

Comment: Hi I would like to correct you on this, instead of getting file_get_contents("example.com/getvalue.php") which wil return a string, try including the file. by include "getvalue.php";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$country_location = [];
$region = [];
foreach($b as $key => $val) {
    foreach($val as $key2 => $val2) {
        $country_location[] = $val2['location'];
        $region_location[] = $val2['regionname'];
    }
}

print_r($country_location);
print_r($region);
```

Comment: I tried using foreach but i got Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error message.

Comment: @Yash This means you don't have an array or are hiding something from us.

Comment: @Rizier123 i got this array from file_get_contents("http://example.com/getvalue.php");

Comment: @Yash What is the **exact** output of: `var_dump($arrayname);` <- Add the output into your question

Comment: @Rizier123 i got "string(1211)" with my array result. when i used var_dump($myarrayname);

Comment: @Yash Exactly. See that: *" **string** (1211)"* You don't have an array. You have a string

Comment: @Rizier123 you are right, now how can i convert it into array...?

Comment: @Yash How does your file looks like from where you get this array? (<- Show it in your question)

Comment: Thanks @aldrin27 for your answer but first i need to convert it into array. Then foreach will work.